# Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'substr' MarkerWithLabel

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I am receiving the below error message when attempting to use MarkerWithLabel.js. There are no errors in the javascript that I can see. In addition the method substr is not used in the javascript. Is there another method call I should be looking for which might invoke this error message?

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'substr'
    (anonymous function)
    (anonymous function)
    rv
    ov
    (anonymous function)
    (anonymous function)
    (anonymous function)
    (anonymous function)
    (anonymous function)
    AO
    FO
    EO
    CO.(anonymous function).ea
    (anonymous function) main.js:32
```

Below is my code which utilizes the javascript and reproduces error

http://jsfiddle.net/X3wG2/4/

Comment: Your fiddle generates a different error `ReferenceError: google is not defined`. How are we supposed to help you if you/we can't reproduce the error?

Comment: The fiddle is just the MarkerWithLabel code (a link to that library would probably be better).  What does your code that uses the MarkerWithLabel library look like? Please add the _code_ (at least the relevant portion, enough to replicate the problem) to your question.

Comment: Yeah, sorry was adding it after making this tread. One second.

Comment: Now I get the error `TypeError: a.url[Gb] is not a function` (this happens in version 4, which is the current version at the time of this comment).

Comment: took me a second to figure out how to use google api library. Jsfiddle is updated now.

Comment: I suggest you first make sure you can reproduce the error, before updating your question.

Comment: The error is reproduced in the above Jsfiddle. I appreciate you looking at it.

Comment: Ah interesting. Firefox says `TypeError: a.url[Gb] is not a function` whereas Chrome says `TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'substr'`. Maybe this already helps you figure out what the problem is.

Comment: Actually it looks like setting  icon: null instead of  icon: {} resolves the issue. I dont know why it was not pointing out this line when I was debugging chrome vs jsfiddle

Comment: Thanks for the help Felix I appreciate you taking the time to look at this. Not sure why it was giving such an error message.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the options for the MarkerWithLabel to set icon: null resolved the issue. When setting icon: {} an error message was thrown. Not sure why the error message was so  non descript from chrome.

Comment: But when icon is `null`, the default icon is visible, you should set a transparent icon.